# import error while adding TextEditor to eclipse plugin - Cannot find the class file for org.eclipse.jface.text.revisions.RevisionInformation

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, text-editor

First I added `org.eclipse.ui.editors` to the dependencies.
Then I added an editor to the extensions

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <view
            class="nattable.examples.ReceivingDataTable"
            id="com.abernard.nattable.ReceivingDataTable"
            name="ReceivingDataTable"
            restorable="true">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
      <editor
            class="nattable.TaskEditor"
            default="false"
            id="DiagnosticTool.editor1"
            name="TaskEditor">
      </editor>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Finally when I edited my class to extend `TextEditor` and import `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` I got the error:

[image: errors]

Comment: What error are you getting?! On the image there's no error description...

Comment: Sorry but it is not clear what error you are getting.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake .. i edited the error image

Answer (score 2):

Add the plugin `org.eclipse.jface.text` to your plugin dependencies to resolve the missing type.

As an absolute minimum your plugin dependencies listed in the MANIFEST.MF should be:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.jface.text,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors
```

(but you may require more)